# ¿Como puedo implementar el DropdownButton?

Tags: flutter

Estoy tratando de hacer que al seleccionar algún nombre de la lista desplegable haga la misma función de los botones amarillo y rosa (respectivamente) y así poder eliminarlos y darle una vista más elegante, no he logrado hacer la sustitución por más que lo intento no puedo Ayuda!!!!

Me temo que pudiese ser algo que no estoy haciendo bien o que estoy pasando por alto.

Este último parrafo es de relleno, ya que me salta el siguiente mensaje al intentar terminar la proegunta "Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles"

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';


class CalculadorMedio extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => Calculadora();
}

class Calculadora extends State<CalculadorMedio> {
  final controller_peso0 = TextEditingController();
  final controller_Peso1 = TextEditingController();
  final controller_ConcentracionProvasoli = TextEditingController();
  final controller_Tiempo = TextEditingController();
  final my_form_key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String TasaCrecimeiento = "";
  String MedioSugerido = "";

  //creamos la clase para calcular peso mujer
  void DiferenciaProvasoli() {
    int decimals = 2;
    num fad = pow(10, decimals);//solo me muestre dos decimales
    int decimals2 = 3;
    num fad2 = pow(10, decimals2); //formula mayor a 10 decimales

    //realizamos las validaciones si algun campo este vacio
    if (my_form_key.currentState!.validate()) {
      double Peso0 = double.parse(controller_peso0.text);
      double Peso1 = double.parse(controller_Peso1.text);
      double Tiempo = double.parse(controller_Tiempo.text);
      double Concentracionprovasoli = double.parse(controller_ConcentracionProvasoli.text);
      double Diferenciapeso = Peso1 - Peso0;
      double Tasacreciemiento = (pow((Peso1/Peso0),(1/Tiempo))-1)*100;
      Tasacreciemiento = (Tasacreciemiento * fad2).round() / fad2;
      double mlprovasoli = ((Diferenciapeso*(Peso0/Peso1))*12.8)/Concentracionprovasoli;
      mlprovasoli = (mlprovasoli * fad).round() / fad;




      setState(() {
        TasaCrecimeiento = "Tasa de crecimiento: $Tasacreciemiento %/día";
      });

      setState(() {
        MedioSugerido = "Agregar $mlprovasoli ml de medio";
      });
    }
  }

  //formula para el hombre
  void DiferenciaProvasoliES() {
    int decimals = 2; //solo me muestre dos decimales
    num fad = pow(10, decimals);
    int decimals2 = 3;
    num fad2 = pow(10, decimals2);


    //realizamos las validaciones si algun campo este vacio
    if (my_form_key.currentState!.validate()) {
      double Peso0Es = double.parse(controller_peso0.text);
      double Peso1Es = double.parse(controller_Peso1.text);
      double ConcentracionProvasoliEs = double.parse(controller_ConcentracionProvasoli.text);
      double Tiempo = double.parse(controller_Tiempo.text);
      double Diferenciapeso = Peso1Es - Peso0Es;
      Diferenciapeso = (Diferenciapeso * fad).round() / fad;
      double Tasacreciemiento = (pow((Peso1Es/Peso0Es),(1/Tiempo))-1)*100;
      Tasacreciemiento = (Tasacreciemiento * fad2).round() / fad2;
      double mlprovasoliES  = ((Diferenciapeso*(Peso0Es/Peso1Es))*20)/ConcentracionProvasoliEs;
      mlprovasoliES  = (mlprovasoliES  * fad).round() / fad;

      setState(() {
        TasaCrecimeiento = "Tasa de crecimiento: $Tasacreciemiento %/día";
      });

      setState(() {
        MedioSugerido = "Agregar $mlprovasoliES ml de medio";
      });
    }
  }

  var _lista = [
    'Seleccionar medio de cultivo',
    'Medio Provasoli',
    'Medio Provasoli ES',
    'Medio Von Stosch',
  ];


String _vista = 'Seleccionar medio de cultivo';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: my_form_key,
        child: ListView(
            children: <Widget> [
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[



                  Container(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),

                  child: Row (children: <Widget>[

                    Container( width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.10,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: controller_peso0,
                          obscureText: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Biomasa inicial (g o kg)',
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10)
                    ),

                    Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.10,
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: controller_Peso1,
                          obscureText: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Biomasa final (g o kg) '
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10)
                    )
                  ],
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  )),

                  Container(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),

                      child: Row (children: <Widget>[

                        Container( width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.7,
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: controller_ConcentracionProvasoli,
                              obscureText: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Concentración del medio',),),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20)),

                        Container( width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3.15,
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: controller_Tiempo,
                              obscureText: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Días de cultivo',),),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20)),
                      ],
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      )),
                  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: DiferenciaProvasoli,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                          color: Colors.orange.shade200,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child:  Text('Provasoli'),),

                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: DiferenciaProvasoliES,
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                          color: Colors.pink.shade200,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Text('Provasoli ES'),),

                      ]),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 30),
                      child: Center (child:
                      Container (width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.2,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                          ),
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            value: _vista,
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_sharp),
                            iconSize: 24,
                            elevation: 2,
                            isExpanded: true,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            underline: Container(),
                            onTap: null,
                            onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                _vista = newValue!;
                              });
                            },
                            items: _lista
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Container (
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/30,
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.05,
                                    child: AutoSizeText(value,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        presetFontSizes: [32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)
                                    )),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ))
                      )),

                  Container( padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 20, 15, 20),

                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.05,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Colors.green.shade300,Colors.green.shade100, Colors.green.shade300]
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                    child: Center(
                      child: AutoSizeText(TasaCrecimeiento,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          presetFontSizes: [32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Container(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 15),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.05,),

                  Container(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(55, 20, 55, 20),

                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.05,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Colors.green.shade300,Colors.green.shade100, Colors.green.shade300]
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                    child: Center(
                      child: AutoSizeText(MedioSugerido,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          presetFontSizes: [32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
    )
]
),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Logré eliminar los botones, usando la funcion onTap:

onTap: _vista.contains("Seleccionar medio de cultivo")?  null : _vista.contains("Provasoli ES")?  DiferenciaProvasoliES : _vista.contains("Provasoli")?  DiferenciaProvasoli : _vista.contains("Medio Von Stosch")?  null : null,

Comment: Quisiera usar la función onChanged pero por más que lo intento, no logro que cambie

onChanged: (String? newValue) {if (_vista.contains("Seleccionar medio de cultivo")) { setState(() { _vista = newValue!; });  }
else if (_vista.contains("Provasoli")) { DiferenciaProvasoli; }
else if (_vista.contains("Provasoli ES")) { DiferenciaProvasoliES; }
else if (_vista.contains('Medio Von Stosch')) { null; } },